# Display error message to users

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write to a text file and im having some issues. I want to write to a text file and on each line have a name, a rate, and hours worked each displayed on a line. I wan to display a error message, and have the user input another value, if the user doesn't input a string for the name, as well as if they don't input a value between 5-50 for the rate and 0-100 for the hours. I just cant think of what to do at this point.

Here is my code, Thanks

```
confirmation = (input("Would you like to add to the payroll file? Enter y for yes, or any other key to end operation: "))

while confirmation == "y":
 name = f.write(str(input("What is the employees name?: ")))

  while name != str:
    name = f.write(str(input("Please enter a name: ")))
  f.write(" ")

  rate = f.write(input("What is the employees hourly rate?: "))
  f.write(" ")

  hours = f.write(input("How many hours did the employee work?: "))
  hours = float (hours)

  f.write(str("\n"))    
  confirmation = (input("Would you like to keep adding to the payroll file? Enter y for yes, or any other key to end operation: "))    


print ("File Closed")

f.close()
```

Comment: Check the input to see if it's in your acceptable range of numbers, if not, show a message.

Comment: Indeed.  You're looking for an "if-then-else" structure.

Comment: I have tried but when i use an if statement it will only repeat once if there is an error. For example                                                                rate = f.write(input("What is the employees hourly rate?: "))
    rate = float (rate)
    if rate < 5 or rate > 50:
       rate = f.write(input("Please enter value between 5-50: "))                    Will only show if one time if an error, and then move on no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` function already returns a string. There's no need for you to `str()`.

You syntax `while name != str` is wrong - if you need to check if it is a string you should use `isinstance(name, str)`

`write()` function doesn't return anything. When you equal something to your `f.write()` function you'll equal it to zero.